# How do I move a folder from one directory to another using C#?

Tags: c#, windows, directory, move

```
A = IO.Directory.GetFiles(Music,"*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
File.Move(Music, path_2)
```

This will allow me to move all the contents in the "Music" folder to path_2 including the files in the subfolders. Is it possible to move the "Music" folder without changing the structure of it?

```
Music
   Classical
       Ballet.txt
       Opera.txt
   Electronic
       Chunk.txt
       IDM.txt
   Jazz
       Hard Pop.txt
       Ragtime.txt
```

Comment: Did you try `Directory.Move` - "*Moves a file or a directory and its contents to a new location.*"

Comment: I had tried using this command, it doesn't work.@TheGeneral

Comment: Doesn't work isn't a technical description of a problem

Comment: "doesn't work" could mean anything. If you need some help, be specific - show the code you wrote, and explain what happens when you run it...do you get an error message? Or some other unexpected result? We can't fix vague problems with invisible code.

Comment: This is the error shown:
System.IO.IOException: Source and destination path must have identical roots. Move will not work across volumes at System.IODirectory.InternalMove(String source DirName, String destDirName, Boolean checkHost) at Form1.Move()